# How to Initiate a service in android watch from phone?

Tags: android, wear-os

I am currently working on gesture recognition using android watch and phone. I have developed one phone app and one watch app. Watch app recognizes the gesture and sends a message to phone to display the gesture. Now I want to start the app in watch from my phone. Is it possible for me to start an app in watch by pressing a button in an app in phone? Or Can I start a service in watch by clicking any button in an app in phone? Basically I want to make the user not to touch watch to start his app. By initiating the watch app, I basically start collecting the sensor data for the app to recognize the gesture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is doable:

1. Send a message to your watch (using MessageApi)
2. Have a WearableListenerService in your app on the watch so your application on the watch can capture the message even if it is not running
3. In that service, start the desired activity.

You can, alternatively, use [WearCompanionLibrary](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-WearCompanionLibrary) that does all of this for you in a simple API.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. So even when the app is not running, a message from phone will be received? How to run the WearableListenerService without starting an app? I am not sure how to do that. I hope the WCL has that code.

Comment: If you want to use WCL, it has a documentation and a sample app so you should be able to do it easily. If you want to do it yourself, you may want to read up on WearableListenerService; that service is invoked by the framework when a message is received for your app, regardless of the app is running or not.

Comment: Hi Ali, I have a doubt. I used WearableListenerService to start an app in watch. I believe this is a background service(please correct me if I am wrong). So what are the chances of it getting killed by Android? Since it is provided by Android itself, will it always run? Regarding my work, I will initiate the service to start an app in watch and use it for recognizing   gestures for a long period of time.

Comment: Anuroop, that is not a service that runs all the time; it is started (via binding) by framework only when there is a message/data for your app, at which time, framework starts that service and shortly after the service's  work is done,  it goes away. You may want to read on services that get started via binding (versus the ones started via startService()) to see the difference.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. So it can be used to start or stop an app in watch from mobile. Once the app is started, it will run as normal I believe. Then can I receive notification in mobile if the app in watch gets killed? Is there a way to do that?